# reading xyz form tf/tfMessage

Tags: ros, kinect, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I am trying to read xyz from tfMessage which publishes the kinect's translation from the pi_tracker or the openni_launch and i want it sent to tum_simulator..

### where is the code

```
geometry_msgs::Twist command;
ros::Publisher pub_takeoff, pub_land, pub_toggle_state, pub_vel;
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transforms;
geometry_msgs::Transform transform;
geometry_msgs::Vector3 translation;


using namespace ros;

void chatterCallback(const tf::tfMessage::ConstPtr& mes)

{

    //command.linear=mes;
    command.linear.x = mes->transforms.transform.translation.x;
    //command.linear.y = mes->y;
    //command.linear.z = mes->z;
    //command.angular.z= mes->z;
ROS_INFO("I received %f %f %f %f/n", command.linear.x, command.linear.y, command.linear.z, command.angular.z);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

 //init subscr node
ros::init(argc, argv, "simkin");
// Create a node handle
ros::NodeHandle n;
// Initialize the node
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/tf", 1000, chatterCallback);
//ros::spin();


 // A publisher for the movement data
 Publisher pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 10);

 // Drive forward at a given speed.  The robot points up the x-axis.
 //geometry_msgs::Twist command;


 Rate rate(10);
 while (ok()) {
   pub.publish(command);
   rate.sleep();
   ros::spinOnce();
 }

 return 0;
}
```

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63196/reading-xyz-form-tf/tfmessage/) by [Silimon Sorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3780/silimon-sorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-05-21**:
What is the question? What goes wrong?

**Comment by [Silimon Sorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3780/silimon-sorin/) on 2013-05-22**:
it doesn't work,the error is that"transform does not name a type"...I need to read the xyz from the /tf...OR I could you the pi_tracker topic /skeleton which is not so compact but is I put in chatterCallback pi_tracker::skeleton (this is the error:error: ‘pi_tracker’ does not name a type
/home/ssr )

**Comment by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on 2015-01-24**:
@Silimon Sorin @ngrennan Did you understand how we should do it for kinect? We get transforms of all the skeletal coordinate frames separately. Guess we should receive them separately! Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the TF library rather than subscribing to the /tf topic directly. Take a look at the [tf documentation](http://ros.org/wiki/tf) and the [tf C++ tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-05-22**:
Agreed. The way you access the tf data is not recommended. If you use the tf topic like this, you will receive the data of all transforms in your system. To get the data of a specific transform, use the tf::TransformListener. Have a look at the above linked tutorials to learn how to use it.